# Just a quick simple ?? about randomizing this slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

I have this slideshow on a website I am building, it works perfectly, but I would like the pictures to randomize. I know there is a ".shuffle" function, but have no idea where to place it.  Can someone please help?`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();
    setInterval(function() { 
        $('#slideshow > div:first')
            .fadeOut(1000)
            .next()
            .fadeIn(1000)
            .end()
            .appendTo('#slideshow');
    },  3000);
});
```

Comment: <div id="slideshow">
 
   <div>
     <img src="advise/image1.jpg">
   </div>
   <div>
     <img src="advise/image2.jpg">
   </div>
   <div>
    <img src="advise/image3.jpg">
   </div>
    <div>
    <img src="advise/image4.jpg">
   </div>
  <div>
    <img src="advise/image5.jpg">
   </div>
   <div>
    <img src="advise/image6.jpg">
   </div>
   
</div>

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a lot of context here (most notably the script that adds the slideshow functionality to #slideshow) but if you know there is a ".shuffle" class in the library you are using that does this what you want to do is going to the "#slideshow" element in your html and add "class='shuffle'" to it. If it already has a class attribute just put a space after the last one and put shuffle there. Do not include the period before shuffle when you add it to the class attribute in the HTML. The period just specifies it is a class for identification in CSS/Javascript.

UPDATE: [Here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zhv5gqmt/) with a basic implementation of how you can shuffle what you currently have. I hope it helps demonstrate what you can do to solve this problem! Let me know if you have any questions but essentially what you do is make use of jqueries 'eq' selector which allows you to select divs within an element (in your case #slideshow). Then you just use javascript to feed it a random number that can only be up to the length of the amount of divs in the element - 1 (look up zero based indexing if that part doesn't make sense). There is some very simplified logic on how to handle it randomly choosing the same slide twice in a row as well:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();
    $slideCount = $("#slideshow > div").length;
    $('#slideshow > div:first').fadeOut(2500);

    setInterval(function() { 
        $firstSlideChosen = Math.floor((Math.random() * $slideCount));
        $('#slideshow > div').eq($firstSlideChosen).show();
        $('#slideshow > div').eq($firstSlideChosen)
            .fadeOut(2500);

        $nextSlide = Math.floor((Math.random() * $slideCount));
        if($nextSlide == $firstSlideChosen){
            if($nextSlide < ($slideCount - 1)) { //if it is not the last in the divs inside of #slideshow
                    $nextSlide++;
                }else{ //it chose the last one so we can only go back
                    $nextSlide--;
                }
        }
        $('#slideshow > div').eq($nextSlide)
                .fadeOut(2500);

    }, 5000
)});
```

Comment: this is a script I copied offline, it works great, but does not shuffle the images.  That is what I am wanting it to do.

Comment: Oh okay if you share the script (if it is not too long) I could help some more but if you know it has the .shuffle functionality already the above should do the trick :).

Comment: This is the whole thing.

Comment: oh okay, I see what you are talking about, no, there is not already a shuffle functionality, I just saw someone had one on the internet, and thought it was a pre made rule.

Comment: Can I see the HTML? I am guessing each slide is loaded into divs inside of #slideshow but knowing that structure could help know how we can create the shuffle functionality.

Comment: <div id="slideshow">
 
   <div>
     <img src="advise/image1.jpg">
   </div>
   <div>
     <img src="advise/image2.jpg">
   </div>
   <div>
    <img src="advise/image3.jpg">
   </div>
    <div>
    <img src="advise/image4.jpg">
   </div>
  <div>
    <img src="advise/image5.jpg">
   </div>
   <div>
    <img src="advise/image6.jpg">
   </div>
   
</div>

Comment: Okay I updated the answer now that I see how you had the HTML structured!